# NPM error when I am trying to install @nuxtjs/firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I am getting this error that I am not understanding and that I don't really know how to fix... I am using Nuxt.js and I want to use firebase along with it, but when I'm trying to firebase.nuxtjs.org and install @nuxtjs/firebase I am getting this error -

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: **************@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: firebase@9.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   firebase@"^9.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer firebase@"^8.3.1" from @nuxtjs/firebase@7.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@nuxtjs/firebase
npm ERR!   @nuxtjs/firebase@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I was hoping you all could help me with it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yow broh, using node current version is not a good Idea, specially if you depend on third party modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the readme of the @nuxtjs/firebase library (https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module), firebase version 9 is currently not supported. Using firebase@8.10.0 and @nuxtjs/firebase@7.6.1 should work.

You can track the progress of when firebase 9 is supported under nuxt here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/573