# Nuxt + Firebase - Correct way to handle environment variables

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I have been trying to develop a fully functional, reusable firebase authentication app however after looking online at multiple different solutions, I have developed the below which works perfectly but from my understanding there is no way to protect the API keys/sensitive data? Is there anyway to use environment variables on the **plugins/firebase.js** file?

The nuxt/firebase docs suggests declaring them within the **nuxt.config.js** file? But when following the docs and trying to install **firebase** & **@nuxtjs/firebase** I keep running into errors. [NPM error when I am trying to install @nuxtjs/firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069491/npm-error-when-i-am-trying-to-install-nuxtjs-firebase)

Is there any definitive/working best practise to follow when working with Nuxt & Firebase?

**~plugins/firebase.js**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx"
};

firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : ''

export const auth = firebase.auth()
export const google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
export const storage = firebase.storage()
export default firebase
```

**~/plugins/fireauth.js**

```js
import { auth } from '~/plugins/firebase.js'

export default (context) => {
  const { store } = context

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        
         console.log(user);
     
         store.dispatch('setUser', user)
         resolve(user)

       }, err => {
         reject(err)
       })
  })
}
```

**Update to @Kissu**

The environment variables are now working as per @kissu's comments below - however the app is now crashing because the **initializeApp()** is not being run.
`Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).`

**~/plugins/firebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/storage'

export default ({ $config }) => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: $config.firebaseConfig.apiKey,
        authDomain: $config.firebaseConfig.authDomain,
        projectId: $config.firebaseConfig.projectId,
        storageBucket: $config.firebaseConfig.storageBucket,
        messagingSenderId: $config.firebaseConfig.messagingSenderId,
        appId: $config.firebaseConfig.appId
    }
    !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : ''
  }


export const auth = firebase.auth()
export const google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
export const storage = firebase.storage()
```

Resources:
https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/
https://dev.to/drewclem/building-user-accounts-with-nuxt-vuex-and-firebase-2o6l

Comment: Did you fixed the error here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69069491/8816585

Comment: Otherwise, check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585) and no, there is no way to hide a private token with frontend only.

Comment: Thanks Kissu, ive tried amending the code as per your suggestion and no success - just to confirm to make sure I am doing it correct:                
1) add a .env file to the root of the file                     
2) declare a env variable e.g. "PRIVATE_VARIABLE=secret"             
3) add to the privateRuntimeConfig in nuxtconfig e.g. "privateRuntimeConfig: {
    API_KEY: process.env.FB_API_KEY }"             
4) in my firebaseConfig call the private variable e.g. "config: {
          apiKey: process.env.API_KEY }"                
Is this correct?

Comment: No, check my answer for the exact part where we have `$config: { myPublicVariable }`. Basically, use the publicRuntimeConfig variable into your plugin.

Comment: Please edit your initial question rather than posting it in comments.

Comment: Apologies, post has been edited. Thanks

Comment: Move `firebaseConfig` to the `nuxt.config.js` file, inside of the `publicRuntimeConfig` key. Then, in your plugin, use `$config: { apiKey }`. Should work fine!

Comment: Thanks @kissu - It is now reading the environment variable as per your suggestion but I am now facing the problem with the firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) not being run... `Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).` 

I have updated the post above.

Comment: This is part of the migration to the latest version if I'm not mistaken. I saw this several times, pretty common. Give a look to [this video](https://youtu.be/zd6ffqoK_EU?t=208) and try to search for this precise error, you should fine a decent amount of answers IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In your Firebase Config, you can use local environment variables (from your `.env` file) using `process.env.VUE_APP_`:

```js
// ~/plugins/firebase.js

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_authDomain,
    projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_messagingSenderId,
    appId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_appId,
    measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_measurementd,
};
```

But be sure to set your Variables in your `.env` file like this:

```js
// ~/.env 
// NOTE: THIS FILE IS NOT COMMITTED TO CODE REPOSITORY / GITHUB AND SHOULD BE IGNORED BY DEFAULT IN YOUR `.gitignore` FILE

// NOTE: For Vue.js environment variables, you must prefix them with `VUE_APP_`
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_apiKey=
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_authDomain=
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_projectId=
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_storageBucket=
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_messagingSenderId=
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_appId=
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_measurementId=
```

Where after the `=` you put your secret keys and ID's. NOTE: Be sure to leave NO SPACE between the `=` and your key. For example:

```
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_apiKey=YOUR.KEY.HERE
...
```

You can read more documentation on VUE_APP Environment Variables here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

This `.env` file should not be committed to Github, or your code repository. Instead, set these variables on your production environment. For example, if you are using Netlify or Heroku, you will want to set Environment Variables with the EXACT same names like `VUE_APP_FIREBASE_apiKey` and set its value to be equal to your Key.

If using Netlify, set your Environment Variables in your Build & Deploy Site Settings:

```
https://app.netlify.com/sites/{{YOUR_SITE_HERE}}/settings/deploys#environment
```